# Fatou's lemma. Prove or disprove.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

Let $(f_{n})$ be a sequence of integrable functions on $\mathbb{R}$. Prove or disprove:

1. $$\begin{align}
   \int_{\mathbb{R}}\lim\inf_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}\leq \lim\inf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{n}
   \end{align}$$
2. $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\lim\inf_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}\geq \lim\inf_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{n}$$
3. $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\lim\sup_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}\leq \lim\sup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{n}$$
4. $$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\lim\sup_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_{n}\geq \lim\sup_{n\rightarrow\infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{n}$$

My works:

1. To show, I provided a counter example $f_{n}=-n1_{[0,1/n]}$. That is , ${\int}_{\mathbb{R}}\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\liminf}f_{n} = 0$ and $\underset{n\rightarrow\infty}{\liminf}\int_{\mathbb{R}}f_{n} = -\infty$.

Am I going the correct way?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by $f_n=-n1_{[0,1/n]}$?

Comment: Yes, so, your example shows that claim 1 fails.  So you would need three more examples (or proofs) to resolve the other claims.  In this problem, none of the statements are quite the ones needed for Fatou, so it gives you good intuition on why all the requirements of Fatou are there.